# Add method to chaining in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-chaining

I am trying to write an auto complete jQuery plugin.

The desired usage:

```
$('.advancedSelect').advancedSelect({/*plugin options*/}).change(function(){})/*.otherJQueryMethods*/;
```

The implementation:

```
$.fn.advancedSelect = function({
    return this.each(function(){
         var $advSel = $('<input/>');
         var $el = $(this).after($advSel).hide();
         /* my codes on desired functionalities */
         /* how is it possible to trigger the chained change method */

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In a comment on my soon-to-be-deleted answer (as it answered a question other than your real question, as it turns out), you've said:

> I was wondering whether we could have a syntax like this:
>
> ```
> $('.advancedSelect').advancedSelect({/*plugin options*/}).onChange(function(){}).css({})
> ```
>
> -and by `.css` I meant any other jQuery's methods.

I would suggest either this:

```
$('.advancedSelect').advancedSelect({/*other plugin options*/, onChange: function(){}}).css({})
```

or this:

```
$('.advancedSelect').advancedSelect({/*plugin options*/}).advancedSelect("onChange", function(){}).css({})
```

... with a fairly strong preference for the first one. :-)

Re that first option, an adjunct you see a lot is an optional "options" method you can use later to change options::

```
// Initial setup
$('.advancedSelect').advancedSelect({/*other plugin options*/, onChange: function(){}}).css({})

// Later, I need to change something
$('.advancedSelect').advancedSelect("options", { onChange: function(){}});
```

---

Side note: If this `change`-like method is to register a change handler, why not just use jQuery's `change` (or `on` with some plugin-specific event name) and have your plugin raise an event? That's how I would handle any kind of event-related thing in a plugin. Look at bootstrap's use of `shown.bs.modal` and such, for instance.

Comment: Using `on` with custom `adv.change` event and `trigger('adv.change')` could be the best alternative to the case. The code would be like:
`$('.advancedSelect').advancedSelect({}).on('adv.change',function(){})`

I guess what you'r trying to say is there is no way to achieve the mentioned syntax, right?

Comment: @hbtb: No reasonable way, no. I mean, you could do this inside your plugin function: `this.onChange = function() { ... };` (e.g., adding a function to *just that one jQuery object*), but I wouldn't call that reasonable. I'd definitely go with your own event name and using `on`.